# Jenkins running out of storage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am totally new to Jenkins, and how it works. I am trying to deploy a new Kunernetes cluster, however i am getting an error:

> Master (the master Jenkins node)
>   Disk space is too low. Only 0.128GB left on /var/lib/jenkins.

I have tried enabling the Clean before checkout and Wipeout respository and force clone.

I have also enabled the discard old builds

However I can not seem to find a way of clearing this error. Any help would be awesome

Thanks and sorry if this is a noob question

Comment: Are u using SCM to pull your code?

Comment: It’s using GitHub plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are running out of space on the machine where the jenkins master is running. You can verify that by running `df -h`.

The solution to free up some space. One way of doing that is to clean unneeded docker stuff by running `docker system prune`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, (apologies for basic question) can you point me in a direction where I run this please?

Comment: On the machine running jenkins.

Comment: As far as I am aware (sorry I inherited this system) It is in a kubernetes cluster on google cloud? Would that be the place to run this?